# Preload all images in folder and all its subfolders

Tags: javascript, php, json, preload

I have an image gallery with hundreds of images (sixty per page) and I would like for those images to start pre-loading upon any page on the site finishing loading (the gallery is where almost every visitor will end up) by adding a script file to the header.  While I have a helpful, small pre-load script in my header already for a few named images (custom scrollbar arrows, drop-down box arrows, and check-box images, plus a few 1800px background-type images for a few pages), I need a script that will find the files in the folders for me as I can't possibly add them all by name (which changes upon upload) or keep the list updated as new photos are added.

However, the file structure is a bit crazy as the gallery script (which I can't change) puts them in a folder such as "/photos/year/month/day/hour" based on the upload day and time.  So, in order to pre-load them, I need the script to look in all of the many subfolders of each year folder I name, down to the hour folder.  (The photos folder has other folders that I don't want pre-loading, so I will have to manually add each year folder to the script.  The year, month, and day folders only have folders; all the photos are in the hour folders.)  The newest images should pre-load first (ex. "/photos/2021/07/03/04/small_xyz123_photo.jpg" should load before "/photos/2021/04/24/12/small_abc987_photo.jpg") since the newest ones show in the gallery first (oldest ones would be pages deep).

Since the gallery script resizes the photos for different uses across the site, I only want the images that begin with "small_" to pre-load, as those are the ones in the gallery listing (ex. the "large_" ones are what they see once they click to open one, and obviously I'm not going to pre-load hundreds of 1600px images onto people's devices).  The script names the files the-size_random-string_original-filename.jpg.

I have come across this script that seems like it will almost do what I need, but since I'm not that familiar with php beyond doing a few things with it the past few months, and this level of javascript is beyond my knowledge, I am not sure how to add the ability to **make it look in every /photos/.../hour subfolder for the images, only choose the "small_*" images, or make it pre-load the newest ones first**.

There is also a warning on the site about security

> "Since the directory to be scanned is specified in a query string it
> would be VERY easy for ANYONE to gain information on your file
> structure/nomenclature. The regular expression used to validate the
> image names on the server-side (the PHP script) will stop any files
> from being listed that do not end in gif, png, jpg, jpeg, bmp or tif.
> If you’re still concerned then simply specify the directory to be
> scanned from within the PHP script instead of having it passed through
> the query string"

and I don't know if that would really be more secure?  Anyone can see the folders where each image is located by looking at View Source or Inspect.  But, if it IS more secure, I would like to know how to add it to the php, too, if that's possible with the subfolder thing.

Also, I assume that once a file has been pre-loaded, it won't be pre-loaded into the cache again upon the script starting over when they go to another page?  Or does the script run until the end even if they move on to another page/another page that calls for the script to run once the new page is done loading?

Of course I first reached out to the author of the script, but never heard back from him.

The script is at this link, but I will also copy it below: https://j11y.io/snippets/preloading-images-from-a-directory/.

PHP:

```
/* PHP file, e.g. scanImageDirectory.json.php */
 
// Check that a callback function has been specified:
if (!isset($_GET['callback']) || !isset($_GET['directory'])) exit;
 
// Use PHP5's scandir function to scan all
// of images directory:
$dirContents = scandir($_GET['directory']);
 
// Define function to confirm each
// filename is a valid image name/extension:
function isImageFile($src) {
    return preg_match('/^.+.(gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|tif)$/i', $src);
}
 
// Loop through directory files and add to
// $arrayContents on each iteration:
$arrayContents = '';
foreach($dirContents as $image) {
    if (isImageFile($image)) {
        $arrayContents .= !empty($arrayContents) ? ',' : '';
        $arrayContents .= '"' . 'images/' . $image . '"';
    }
}
 
// Prepate JSON(P) output
$output = $_GET['callback'] . '({'images':[' . $arrayContents . ']});';
 
// Output the output:
echo $output;
```

JavaScript:

```
/* JavaScript Component */
 
function preloadImagesFromDirectory(dir) {
 
    if(!dir) return;
 
    function getJSON(URL,success){
 
        // Create new function (within global namespace)
        // (With unique name):
        var uniqueID = 'json'+(+(new Date()));
            window[uniqueID] = function(data){
                success && success(data);
            };
 
        // Append new SCRIPT element to DOM:
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild((function(){
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = URL.replace('callback=?','callback=' + uniqueID);
            return script;
        })());
 
    }
 
    function preload(srcArray) {
        for(var i = 0; i < srcArray.length; i++) {
            (new Image()).src = srcArray[i];
        }
    }
 
    // Get that JSON data:
    getJSON('scanImageDirectory.php?directory=' + encodeURIComponent(dir) + '&callback=?', function(data){
        return data.images ? preload( data.images ) : false;
    });
 
}
```

HTML

```
// We don't want to disturb anything so we'll wait
// until everything's done loading before preloading:
window.onload = function(){
    preloadImagesFromDirectory('images/');
}
```

Thanks to all who can help!

Comment: Simply (1) scan the files with name starting with "small_" first (something like **glob** function), and (2) use  something like **filemtime** function to sort the file by modified date so that you can load the "newest" files by the preload function.

Comment: @KenLee Thanks!  I don't know how to do that, but maybe you or someone else can help me figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

My way to load all images asynchronously with a loading screen

```html
        beforeMount() {
            console.log("beforeMount clientApp");
            this.$isLoading(true); // loading screen display
            const assets = require.context(
                '../public',
                true,
                /^.*(\.jpg|\.png)$/
            ).keys();
            const getImage = url => (
                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const image = new Image()                    
                    image.onload = e => {
                    resolve(image)
                    }
                    image.onerror = e => {
                        reject(Error("Network Error"))
                    }
                    image.src = url
                })
            );
            const loadImages = assets => (
                 assets.map(getImage)
            )
            Promise.all(loadImages(assets))
            .then(()=>{
                console.log("images loaded")
                this.$isLoading(false);
            }) // Done callback
            .catch((e)=>{
                console.error("images error")
            })
        },
```